# How to remove a div but prevent the scroll position to be changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**What do i want to achive?**
I want to remove a div which isnt visible(for the user not the css atribute) anymore on the screen because i let the html and body scroll to a div with jquery(scrollTop). Now i want to remove the div which was visible beforr i scrolled down with jquery.

Edit: After removing the .header div, the #begining should be the top of the page and the .header div should be removed forever.

**What is the problem?**
After i scrolled down and removed the div with the following line of code: `$('.header').css('display','none');` the scroll position changes.

**Code to scroll down and remove the div.**

```
function scrollToBegining(){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#begining").offset().top
        }, 750);

        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.header').css('display','none');
        },750);

    }
```

**Problem visualized:**
[GIF of the problem (Watch to understand better)](https://gyazo.com/03ffdccf3aac177a267cb7e1181090f8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is odd, but I think a better choice is to `slideUp` the div instead of scrolling:

```
function scrollToBegining(){
    $('.header').slideUp(750);
}
```

Obviously, rename the function since it's no longer scrolling.

Comment: Yeah, this works, but it looks a bit different. Not too bad, but do you have another idea why im getting this "scrollbar jumping" effect?

Comment: It's just because of what you're doing. I think this method is nicer because if you wanted to bring the header back you'd just reverse it with slideDown. It's much cleaner and much more concise.

Comment: i quite agree with you. Thansk for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `visibility: hidden` to hide the div but reserve its space. Also, sometimes the scroll position has to be changed when you use `display: none`.

Comment: Yes, but i dont want to reserve the space. It should be gone forever and the #begining is after removing the .header div the top of the page. But thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
visibility: hidden
```

is what you are looking for, but another solution I use with this kind of issue is instead of scrolling down to your second div, have the initial div shrink its height in a uniform animation until it is 0. This prevents the weird shuddering scroll issue you are experiencing

Comment: kinda like the jquery slideUp() function?

Comment: yep that would work too if you are using jquery in your application

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector('#header h1').addEventListener('click', closeHeader)
function closeHeader(){
 document.querySelector('#header').classList.add("hidden");
}
```

```css
#header {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
}

#content {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  text-align: center;
}

.hidden {
    display: none !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1>
    HEADER
  </h1>
</div>
<div id="content">
  CONTENT
</div>
```

Comment: To show the header again:  `document.querySelector('#header').classList.remove("hidden");`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i want to use it with the jquery scrollTop() function. I applied your code and after i let js scroll down i used your line of code: document.querySelector('#header').classList.add("hidden"); to hide the header but.. the problem is still there (scrollbar jumps down)

Comment: The content gets smaller and the scrollbar stays at the scroll-index. Then you need to scroll the difference up or down. `var startIndex = scroll.index; hideHeader(); var newIndex = scroll.index; var scrollHeight = startIndex - newIndex;` But i dont know how you get the scroll indexes.. Just saying what you could try.

Comment: The problem of your funktion is: 1) You scroll to the position of the `#begining` 2) you remove the `#header` 3) content gets smaller 4) scroll animation lasts 750ms. 5) remove div last 0ms --> you are at 300px, than remove 300px --> you are at 600px --> scrollbar jumps from 300px to 600px.

Comment: i tried it with `window.scrollTo(0,0)` but that didnt worked, then i added a 1ms delay, still not working, i tried 10ms, which worked but obviously it does look choppy..